# Implementing Montogomery Modular Reduction/Multiplication (MMM)

Tags: rsa, verilog, system-verilog

I have been trying to implement Montogomery Modular Reduction in Verilog and encountered an error while doing so. Attaching the code below:

```
module  MMM  ( a , b , c , y ) ;

// Parameters
//
parameter  N  =  32 ;  // Default value of N

// Inputs
//
input   [N-1:0]  a ;  // N-bit input a
input   [N-1:0]  b ;  // N-bit input b
input   [N-1:0]  c ;  // N-bit input c

// Outputs
//
output  [N-1:0]  y ;  // N-bit output y

// Internal nets
//
wire    [N-1:0]  q ;  // N-bit q array
//wire    [N+1:0]  t  [0:N-1] ;  // (N+2)-bit temporary iteration variable t, bus array of N
wire    [N+1:0]  s ;  // 


// Initial value of S
//
assign  s[0]  =  0 ;

// Iteration
//
genvar  i ;
generate
  for  ( i  =  0 ;  i  <=  N-1 ;  i  =  i + 1 )
    begin  :  iterate
      assign  q[i]  =  (s[i] + a[i] * b) % 2;
      assign  s[i+1]  =  (s[i] + q[i] * c + a[i] * b) / 2;
      if (s[N] >= c) 
      assign  y  =  s[N] - c ;
      else      
      assign y  =  s[N] ;

    end  // iterate
endgenerate

//assign MMM[a, b, c] = y;

endmodule
```

The error is:

> The generate if condition must be a constant expression.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I have access to a similar code that works perfectly fine
It has the following lines of code in it-
assign  q[i]  =  s[i][0]  ^  ( a[i] & b[0] ) ;
      assign  t[i]  =  s[i]  +  ( q[i] ? c : 0 ) ;
      assign  s[i+1]  =  ( t[i] >> 1 ) ;

I think the problem here is with the if..else condition or its definition.

Comment: I found out where I was going wrong. The if statement had to be placed outside the for loop to get the results. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `if` inside a generate must be decidable at compilation time, you are using a signal as a condition of the if block. I understand that what you mean is to create a mux with that expression in the selector, but the compiler don't.

you could wrap the `iterate` logic in a procedural `always` block and then you would be able to use the `if`  statement.
Also, the assignment to y should be outside the `iterate` block, otherwise it will have multiple drivers.

Fixing these two problems you have

```sv
module  MMM  ( a , b , c , y ) ;


// Parameters
//
parameter  N  =  32 ;  // Default value of N

// Inputs
//
input   [N-1:0]  a ;  // N-bit input a
input   [N-1:0]  b ;  // N-bit input b
input   [N-1:0]  c ;  // N-bit input c

// Outputs
//
output  [N-1:0]  y ;  // N-bit output y

// Internal nets
//
wire    [N-1:0]  q ;  // N-bit q array
//wire    [N+1:0]  t  [0:N-1] ;  // (N+2)-bit temporary iteration variable t, bus array of N
wire    [N+1:0]  s ;  // 


// Initial value of S
//
assign  s[0]  =  0 ;

// Iteration
//
genvar  i ;
generate
  for  ( i  =  0 ;  i  <=  N-1 ;  i  =  i + 1 )
    begin  :  iterate
      assign  q[i]  =  (s[i] + a[i] * b) % 2;
      assign  s[i+1]  =  (s[i] + q[i] * c + a[i] * b) / 2;
    end  // iterate

endgenerate
assign  y  =  s[N] >= c ? s[N] - c : s[N];

//assign MMM[a, b, c] = y;


endmodule
```

Disclaimer: Maybe there are more errors, I did not notice.

Comment: Yes that's absolutely correct! I made the above change already and everything works fine. Thanks for the answer anyway :D